# How to decrement the counter in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Let's assume I have a passage with coordinates as:

```
  (0,0) (1,0) ...(10,0)
```

Now bunch of 5 persons enter from (0,0) one by one with 0.5 intervals.

So I have defined a counter with variable-A ,  starting from 0-6 in JMeter with the following function in MQTT  publish.

```
 {     
  ${__intSum(${A},-0.5,)}.${__Random(0,9,)
  }
  ..
  },
  ..
  {
```

${__intSum(${A},-2.5,)}.${__Random(0,9,
)

```
  }
  ..
  }
```

So when I run the above functions in loop, the person get treated as entering the passage one by one with 0.5 intervals..

Now the problem is , how to write the similar functions, if the bunch of 5  person's with same interval 0.5, enters from (8,0)... How to have the counter in decrement fashion or the Jmeter support any other functions to replicate this scenario. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's your problem? "Increment" value of the [Counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element doesn't have to be a positive number, you can put a negative one there as well:

[image]

So the counter will be decremented by 1 on each iteration of it's respective [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller)

[image]

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)